# python: add str and str.title() to list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am reading in a file with words, like this:

```
stop_words = [x for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')]
```

but I also need the title() version of the word in the same list. Can I do this using one list comprehension?

Comment: what do you mean `title() version`

Comment: @MooingRawr he probably means `x.title()`

Comment: @MooingRawr yes, that's what I meant. Sorry!

Comment: You can't close the file this way. You don't need one list comprehension. Python is not for minification, it is for clarity. `import this`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one (nested) list comprehension:

```
stop_words = [y for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n') for y in (x, x.title())]
```

Edit: You actually shouldn't do it like this, because you lose the file object to the open file and can't close it.  You should use a Context Manager:

```
with open('stopwords.txt', 'r') as f:
    stop_words = [y for x in f.read().split('\n') for y in (x, x.title())]
```

Comment: @ZachGates you can even do `for x in f`,  though I think that keeps newlines

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
stop_words = [[x, str(x).title()]  for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')]
```

which will produce nested list.

```
[ [x, x titled], [y, y titled] ...]
```

Comment: They want `[x, x.title(), y, y.title(), ...]`

Comment: sorry I did not understand, fixed using nested list

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible in one line of code:

```
stop_words = [x for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')] +  [x.title() for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')]
```

Comment: Which would be 2 comprehensions.

Comment: One liner != One list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I was looking for what Patrick Haugh posted

Comment: my bad... glad you found a better answer though!